# Can I echo the alias text every time I run them without running into pipeline issues?

Tags: bash, echo, pipeline, alias

For learning purposes, I would like to automatically print out the aliases I use each time I run them.  My hope is that it will help me learn what some of the useful flags involved in the commands do, and also keep my memory fresh for pieces in aliases involving pipelines.

I know I can just run `type alias-name` each time I'd like to remember, but I want this to happen automatically.

So far I have this script which I source from ~/.bashrc

```bash
declare -a ALIASES
while read -r; do
   ALIASES+=("$REPLY")
done < <(alias)

for i in "${ALIASES[@]}"
do
    ALIAS_AND_NAME=$(awk -F '=' '{print $1}' <<< "$i")  # puts the keyword alias and the alias itself into the variable
    NAME_ONLY=$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "$ALIAS_AND_NAME") # removes the keyword alias
    
    COMMAND_AFTER_EQUALS=$(sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//g' <<< "$i")
    # regex: matches up until the '=', then also matches '=', and replaces the match with nothing  (removes the alias piece)
    ALIAS_COMMAND=$(sed -e "s/^'//" -e "s/'$//" <<< "$COMMAND_AFTER_EQUALS")
    # remove single quotes

    # now remake the alias, first echoing what the alias is, then running the command
    alias $NAME_ONLY="echo ~~~alias $NAME_ONLY=\'$ALIAS_COMMAND\'~~~ 1>&2; $ALIAS_COMMAND"
done
```

As far as I can tell, this works just as I'd like whenever an alias is used standalone.  The issue I'm running into now is when aliased commands like

```bash
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

are used in pipelines.  I believe now the input is going from the previous pipeline command into the echo statement in the new alias.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Expand to a _group_; `... | { echo ...; grep ... }` lets `grep` read input (because `echo` ignores it and leaves it still on stdin). Mind, the tricky problem is that an alias won't let you pass the original arguments through to something inside a group; a _function_ makes that easy, but aliases are far less capable (to the point that in the #bash IRC channel, the `!alias` factoid has traditionally read "if you have to ask, use a function instead").

Comment: Presumably, these are aliases someone else defined, rather than ones you defined to ease a task you found to be repetitive. I would recommended *not* using such alias until  you already understand what the "repetitive" options are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an alias *on its own* for what you're trying to do -- but it can be pulled off if you pair that alias with a function:

```
write_alias_warning_and_execute() {
  local orig_alias_name orig_alias_str orig_alias_q args_q
  orig_alias_name=$1; shift
  orig_alias_str=$1; shift
  printf -v args_q '%q ' "$@"
  printf -v orig_alias_q '%q' "$orig_alias_str"
  echo "alias $orig_alias_name=$orig_alias_q" >&2
  eval "command $orig_alias_str $args_q"
}

for alias_name in "${!BASH_ALIASES[@]}"; do
  alias_content=${BASH_ALIASES[$alias_name]}
  if [[ $alias_content = *write_alias_warning_and_execute* ]]; then
    echo "alias $alias_name is already wrapped; skipping" >&2
  fi

  printf -v new_alias 'write_alias_warning_and_execute %q %q' "$alias_name" "$alias_content"
  BASH_ALIASES[$alias_name]=$new_alias
done
```

Some notes, stylistic and otherwise:

- Note that we're using lowercase names for variables the script above defines itself. That's because all-caps names are in a namespace used for variables meaningful to the shell and operating system; names *outside* that space [are reserved for "application use"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html); your script, in this context, is an application.
- There's no need to parse the output of the `alias` command, because (in the reserved meaningful-to-the-shell-itself all-caps namespace) bash exposes an associative array, `BASH_ALIASES`, containing the names and content of all defined aliases.
- Using `printf %q "$var"` (for compatibility: bash 5.0+ allows the newer and better `${var@Q}`) ensures that we're escaping our strings in a way that evaluates back to their original text, thereby avoiding injection attacks and data-centric bugs as are otherwise [associated with `eval`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).
- The `command` builtin is used to prevent recursion, ensuring that our `eval` doesn't re-invoke the alias itself.
- Consider making a habit of using functions instead of aliases *in the first place*. That is to say, instead of `alias grep='grep --color'`, one can run `grep() { command grep --color "$@"; }`. In that context, adding additional commands to the function can look like `grep() { echo "adding --color to grep" >&2; command grep --color "$@"; }`

Answer (score 1):

> I believe now the input is going from the previous pipeline command into the echo statement in the new alias.

That is correct. [Alias substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01) if performed before application of Shell Grammar rules.
With your grep alias, `echo str | grep` would become `echo str | echo grep='grep --color=auto'; grep`

> Is there a way to avoid this?

You could change your script to rewrite your aliases like this, but this would have the side effect of setting a variable.

```
alias grep="_unusedVar=$(echo grep='grep --color=auto' >&2) grep --color=auto"
```

@charles-duffy's [answer using functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77770776/1743460) is a much better solution.

Comment: "change the behavior of scripts" -- moot here; aliases don't work in scripts at all unless one goes out of one's way to reenable them. But I'm curious as to exactly what changes you're referring to; the only command with a meaningful difference between direct and function-wrapped execution that comes immediately to mind is `declare`, which the OP is deeply unlikely to be using in an alias.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the feedback. I edited the answer according to your concerns.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `f() { echo hi; }; var1=foo f; declare -p var1` results in `bash: declare: var1: not found` on bash 5.2.15 _and_ bash 3.2.57. Are you sure you're not thinking about some non-bash shell where functions behave more like special builtins in this context?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you are absolutely correct. The assignments do not persist bash (nor in dash), altough that could be the case per POSIX: "If the command name is a function that is not a standard utility implemented as a function, variable assignments shall affect the current execution environment during the execution of the function. It is unspecified: Whether or not the variable assignments persist after the completion of the function".

Comment: Perhaps change "will persist" to "may, in other POSIX-compliant shells, persist"?

Comment: I'm not sure we may realisticaly find one such variable-persisting shell. I removed that from my answer. Thanks for the feedback!